# How do I switch between GUI and command line startup?

Tags: boot, 16.04, command-line, gui

I'm not sure what I did, but my computer now starts to a command line interface, rather than a GUI. How do I switch between GUI and command line startup?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the content of `/etc/default/grub` or specifically the values of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`? See “[How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814)” if you need help with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (or Ctrl+Alt+<kbd>F3</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>).
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a virtual console, and you can run terminal commands from the console. For example, you can run terminal commands from the virtual console to repair your boot problem, but Ubuntu Server boots to a virtual console by default. To bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen run this command:

   ```
    sudo systemctl start lightdm.service
   ```

   In 16.04 and later run this command instead to bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen:

   ```
    sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```
5. If you get stuck in a virtual console, press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to exit from the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is something not running properly that avoid the desktop to start properly, but first try this:

press `Alt + F7` (or repeatedly `Alt + Right` ) and you will get back to the GUI session.

if it does not work, in the command line type

```
startx
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked:

```
sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock    
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y  
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I don't understand. 