# grub not loading Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus Vivo laptop alongside Windows 10. That loaded correctly. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 20.04 by manually creating partitions. The installation went smoothly, however on restart, grub doesn't load Ubuntu 20.04 but shows a terminal instead. I tried Boot-Repair via a live USB, but it didn't work.

Here a link to [Boot-Repair report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/B9kwv9rPSV/).

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (3.61-4.03) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 ........>..sr>........p.8...0...~.....~...f...M.f.f....f..0~....>E}.u......
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 7856530 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                       The integrity check of the ADV area failed. No errors 
                       found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 10 on sda3

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000,0003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,a79d2df9-4212-47e0-b432-fbbf1fafc664,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...})...............
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a79d2df9-4212-47e0-b432-fbbf1fafc664,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003* UEFI: hp v236w 0009, Partition 1  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x15,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0xfc5c173b,0x800,0x1ce7800)..BO



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda6    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda8    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda9    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda8    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda9    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda4    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda6    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda8    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda9    : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: E28396D1-E1AC-4593-89BB-922C4A46F666
           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1        2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
sda2      534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3      567296  297527295 296960000 141.6G Microsoft basic data
sda4   848977920 1400428543 551450624   263G Microsoft basic data
sda5  1400428544 1951883263 551454720   263G Microsoft basic data
sda6  1951885312 1953523711   1638400   800M Windows recovery environment
sda7   832976896  848977919  16001024   7.6G Linux swap
sda8   297527296  337526783  39999488  19.1G Linux filesystem
sda9   337526784  477526015 139999232  66.8G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 14.46 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xfc5c173b
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 30310399 30308352 14.5G  b W95 FAT32

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:152GB:152GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
8:152GB:173GB:20.5GB:ext4::;
9:173GB:244GB:71.7GB:ext4::;
7:426GB:435GB:8193MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
4:435GB:717GB:282GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:717GB:999GB:282GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:999GB:1000GB:839MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:hp v236w:;
1:1049kB:15.5GB:15.5GB:fat32::boot;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     9683-38A0                            a79d2df9-4212-47e0-b432-fbbf1fafc664 SYSTEM   EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               b09a32e4-70bc-479b-b134-b0645eeca389          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     DEA0857AA0855A43                     f3bd20b9-ff5b-4698-85bb-700a06cee016 OS       Basic data partition
├─sda4 ntfs     C854CA8154CA71AC                     7d899b33-1d27-41f0-b6ee-e696916a0ca0          Basic data partition
├─sda5 ntfs     FE1AD14B1AD10217                     74b3171d-e99f-469f-af9a-e9a8f8ec8fda          Basic data partition
├─sda6 ntfs     EEA08356A0832465                     dc37e61c-33cb-459e-ad5a-8617fa3df6f8 RECOVERY Basic data partition
├─sda7 swap     455b66d3-da04-437d-9f42-b599b2a26cba d765f7e4-7d19-4238-8668-9c550fab6f02          
├─sda8 ext4     5323d7bc-4339-4c44-86bf-8ff4d879e0f6 e7909a77-09ea-4628-8a33-c728d3142fe0          
└─sda9 ext4     48ec757e-c739-4b5d-813f-0fe5642a4833 a8864d61-190f-4dd5-aa65-0e7ff597f47d          
sdb                                                                                                
└─sdb1 vfat     7DBB-1403                            fc5c173b-01                          TWINCY   

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1                          /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi
sda3               51.4G  64% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda4                          /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
sda5                          /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sda6                          /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
sda8               13.1G  25% /mnt
sda8                          /mnt/boot-sav/sda8
sda9                          /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot
sdb1               10.7G  26% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1              rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda3              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda4              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda6              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda8              rw,relatime
sda8              rw,relatime
sda9              rw,relatime
sdb1              ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

========================== sda8/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=5323d7bc-4339-4c44-86bf-8ff4d879e0f6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=48ec757e-c739-4b5d-813f-0fe5642a4833 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=455b66d3-da04-437d-9f42-b599b2a26cba none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=48ec757e-c739-4b5d-813f-0fe5642a4833  /boot       ext4    defaults      0       2
UUID=9683-38A0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sda8/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda8: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 143.606441498 = 154.196242432  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 143.606441498 = 154.196242432  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic                  2
 158.175811768 = 169.839984640  boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic.efi.signed       1
 143.606441498 = 154.196242432  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2

===================== sda8: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17123 Apr 15 11:31 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42128 Apr 15 11:31 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Apr 15 11:31 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Apr 15 11:31 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Apr 15 11:31 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15 11:31 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Apr 15 11:31 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title UNetbootin
timeout 100

label unetbootindefault
menu label Default
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash ---

label ubnentry0
menu label ^Help
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry1
menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed  quiet splash ---

label ubnentry2
menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing (safe graphics)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed  quiet splash nomodeset ---

label ubnentry3
menu label ^Install Ubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity  quiet splash ---

label ubnentry4
menu label ^Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity  quiet splash nomodeset ---

label ubnentry5
menu label Test ^memory
kernel /install/mt86plus
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry6
menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/ubninit 

label ubnentry7
menu label Ubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash ---

label ubnentry8
menu label Ubuntu (safe graphics)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash nomodeset ---

label ubnentry9
menu label OEM install (for manufacturers)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append initrd=/casper/initrd file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---


==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
            ?? = ??             menu.c32                                       1

=============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux ===============

 menu.c32                           :  COM32R module (v4.xx)


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 2168: cd: /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/efi/: No such file or directory
/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 2168: cd: /mnt/boot-sav/sda4/: No such file or directory
/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 2168: cd: /mnt/boot-sav/sda5/: No such file or directory
/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 2168: cd: /mnt/boot-sav/sda6/: No such file or directory
/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 2168: cd: /mnt/boot-sav/sda8/boot/: No such file or directory
/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 884: [: 2.73495e+09: integer expression expected

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot) and [How do I switch between GUI and command line startup?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960057/)